# Alternatives to hosting WordPress post content?

Tags: hosting, cdn

Our posts are very verbose HTML documents that average 5MB in file size. Although the WordPress database does a decent job of serving these files, it costs us a lot in storage hosting. Due to this, is there a way to store `post_content` on a CDN and still serve it with WordPress?

Comment: just your markup (HTML and text content) of one site is 5mb sized?! maybe you would need to improve your HTML by removing redundant nested div container. Or try to split contents into several pages. Or try loading contents lazy. But sorry i have no answer to serving the contents via a CDN.

Comment: Don't know how costly your storage hosting is, but I doubt you'll find a good solution that won't cost you more. A somewhat risky, yet a possible solution, would be to store your post content as HTML files in private Google Storage or AWS S3 buckets and fetching them each time you need to edit or display the content on the front-end. As @AndréKelling said, you should probably first try to optimize your HTML output or split the content into pages

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The HTML we have are auto-generated legal documents from a 3rd party that are hundreds of pages in length.